# Find a weakly singular kernel function for an estimation of a kernel

Tags: estimation

> > Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n (n>1)$ be a bounded domain and $0<\alpha<n$. Show, that the kernel function
> >     $$
> > k(x,y):=(\arctan(\lVert x-y\rVert))^{-\alpha}\text{ for }x\neq y
> > $$
> >     can be estimated by a kernel function that is weakly singular, i.e. that
> >     $$
> > \lvert k(x,y)\rvert\leq\frac{\lvert a(x,y)\rvert}{\lVert x-y\rVert^{\alpha}}.
> > $$
> >     for a function $a\in L^{\infty}(\Omega\times\Omega)$.

My idea is to use the mean value theorem.
$$
\arctan(\lVert x-y\rVert)=\frac{\lVert x-y\rVert}{1+\xi^2}>\frac{\lVert x-y\rVert}{1+\lVert x-y\rVert^2}
$$
for a $\xi\in (0,\lVert x-y\rVert)$.

$$
\Rightarrow \lvert k(x,y)\rvert=\left\lvert\frac{1}{(\arctan(\lVert x-y\rVert))^{\alpha}}\right\rvert=\frac{1}{(\arctan(\lVert x-y\rVert))^{\alpha}}\leq\frac{(1+\lVert x-y\rVert^2)^{\alpha}}{\lVert x-y\rVert^{\alpha}}
$$

So I found
$$
a(x,y):=(1+\lVert x-y\rVert^2)^{\alpha},
$$
which is to my opinion in $L^{\infty}(\Omega\times\Omega)$, because
$$
\lvert a(x,y)\rvert=(1+\lVert x-y\rVert^2)^{\alpha}\leq (1+(2M)^2)^{\alpha}<\infty
$$
with $M>\lVert\omega\rVert~\forall~\omega\in\Omega$, because $\Omega$ is bounded.

So $a$ is bounded and then in $L^{\infty}(\Omega\times\Omega)$.

Could you please say me, if my proof resp. estimation is okay?

With greetings

math12

Comment: Your proof looks good, though you might want to be explicit that you're using the _$1$-dimensional_ MVT (otherwise there's potential cause for skepticism, since $\Omega$ needn't be convex), and you should probably be explicit that your $a$ is bounded almost everywhere (i.e., not on the diagonal on $\Omega \times \Omega$).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. But I did mention that I used the mean value theorem - or waht do you mean?

Comment: There's a "multi-variable" version of the MVT that looks at $f\bigl((1-t)x + ty\bigr)$, but the proof requires convexity of $\Omega$ (since the argument of $f$ lies on the segment from $x$ to $y$). It took me a minute or two to realize this was _not_ the basis of your argument. :)

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you mean!... Thanks, then I will indeed add that I used the one-dim. MVT.